# Import a function that requires a function loaded on global

Tags: python, function, global, environment

I want to call a function from existing file that requires functions already called in global environmet.

Here's an example of a function that was created in a .py file:

```
def test_func(param): 
    sqrt = math.sqrt(param)  
    return sqrt
```

When I try to run:

```
import math

from test_func import *

test_func(param=4)
```

I got the error:

```
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

How can I call this function correctly?

Comment: Why do you not import math in the file where the function is defined?

Comment: Right.  Nothing in Python is inherited by modules -- globals are only global within a file.  If a module needs `math`, then it has to `import math`.

Comment: You would need to import math where test_func is defined